# Python+kivy text input on_text_validate event

Tags: python-3.x, events, kivy

I can't find out why this always causes an error:

kv

```
<OPP_Form>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    opp_number: kv_OPP_number
    project_name : kv_project_name
    BoxLayout:
        height: "40dp"
        size_hint_y: None
        orientation: "horizontal"
        Label:
            text: "Zadejte OPP cislo"
            multiline: 'False'
            on_text_validate: root.validate_opp()
```

py

```
class OPP_Form(BoxLayout):
    def validate_opp(self):
        oppRegex = regex.compile(r'\d\d-\d\d\d\d\d\d')
        if (regex.match(oppRegex, self.opp_number.text) is None):
            print("Wrong OPP number")
        else:
            OPP = self.opp_number.text
```

I receive the following error:

> AttributeError: text_validate
>      File "C:\Data\Anaconda3\envs\opp_folder\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 630, in _apply_rule
>        raise AttributeError(key)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I guess on_text_validate is the problem. maybe you just wanted on_text

Comment: Solved. I'm blind

Answer (score 2):

*I am just adding the answer @PalimPalim had in a comment to help others out*

```
<OPP_Form>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    opp_number: kv_OPP_number
    project_name : kv_project_name
    BoxLayout:
        height: "40dp"
        size_hint_y: None
        orientation: "horizontal"
        Label:
            text: "Zadejte OPP cislo"
            multiline: 'False'
            on_text: root.validate_opp() //change this line
```